# How to make ExecuteNonQuery return -1 when when it goes through the catch statement which logs the failed query into a log table?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure that inserts to a log table when the queries executes successfully or fails. It looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_stackoverflow]
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION trans1
        INSERT INTO tablename...

        INSERT INTO logtablename...

        COMMIT TRANSACTION trans1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION trans1
        END
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        INSERT INTO logtablename...
    END CATCH 
END
```

C# code looks something like this

```
// isSuccessful is boolean
isSuccessful = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
```

I wanted it to return -1 when `ExecuteNonQuery()` gets invoked so that `isSuccessful` would return false but it always returns true, maybe because of the query that inserts to the log table upon on the catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I can interpret that basically you want to set the value for 'IsSuccessful' Bool field on basis of value returned by executeNonQuery method; In this case,  you can also try using an "output" parameter and set its different value one in Try block and other in Catch block; on basis of the value returned by Output parameter, you could easily figure out whether operation was successful or not and accordingly set value for IsSuccessful field. Hope this will help you.